# If $d(x_n,A)\to0$ can we conclude $(x_n)$ has a cluster point in $A?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

This question occured to me which I cannot resolve.

> Let $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ and $A$ be a compact subset of $X.$ If $d(x_n,A)\to0$ can we conclude $(x_n)$ has a cluster point in $A?$

I think it will be true, may be closeness is playing the vital role. But I cannot give a rigourous proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(x_n)$ is allowed to be in $A$, then not necessarily. For example, we could take a singleton set $A$, and let $(x_n)$ be constant in $A$. Otherwise it's true, and a proof follows.

For each $n$, let $a_n \in A$ such that $d(x_n, a_n) < d(x_n, A) + 2^{-n}$. Then we have a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ that converges to some $a \in A$. Then
$$d(x_{n_k}, a) \le d(x_{n_k}, a_{n_k}) + d(a_{n_k}, a) < d(x_{n_k}, A) + 2^{-n_k} + d(a_{n_k}, a) \to 0,$$
hence $x_{n_k} \to a \in A$.

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Comment: Can't we say: If $(x_n)$ is allowed to be in $A$ then by sequncial compactness it has a cluster point in $A.$ As for your example, the constant term is the cluster point.

Comment: @Jave What definition do you use for "cluster point"?

Comment: If every neighbourhood contains infinitely many terms of the sequence

Comment: @Jave In that case, you're right.

Comment: thank you so much